# Lazy loading in EFCore loads all the data even if not accessed

Tags: asp.net-core, entity-framework-core, lazy-loading

I have been trying to use lazy loading in ASP.NET core 6, I have followed the documentation to do so. However, the behavior of the lazy loading is not the same as described in the docs

> Lazy loading means that the related data is transparently loaded from the database when the navigation property is accessed. [Here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/querying/related-data/)

```
builder.Services.AddDbContext<AppDbContext>(
    options => options.UseLazyLoadingProxies()
     .UseSqlServer(builder.Configuration.GetConnectionString("Default")));
```

Currently I have the following entities

```
    public class Book 
    {
        public long Id { get; set; }
        public string Name { get; set; }

        public long AuthorId { get; set; }
        public virtual Author Author { get; set; }
    }

    public class Author
    {
        public long Id { get; set; }
        public string Name { get; set; }
    }
```

And I have this endpoint

```
[HttpGet]
public IEnumerable<Book> GetBooks()
  {
      var list = _appDbContext.Books.ToList();
      return list;
  }
```

And the resulted SQL quires are

```
SELECT [b].[Id], [b].[AuthorId], [b].[Name]
FROM [Books] AS [b]


SELECT [a].[Id], [a].[Name]
FROM [Author] AS [a]
WHERE [a].[Id] = @__p_0
```

So in the endpoint I am not accessing the property Author inside Book entity, then why ef core is loading data that I dont need it kink of like eager loading but with two queries.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After investigation I realized that AutoMapper was accessing the Author so that is why its always retrieving the Author data.

So, lazyloading in EFCore is not convenient currently.

Comment: https://docs.automapper.org/en/stable/Queryable-Extensions.html

Comment: It looks like you're not using Autmapper properly. With ProjectTo it doesn't trigger lazy loading. But since you don't show any AutoMapper-related code all you say in your Q&A is a black box, only useful to you.